# PPP demand dial with modem bank in linux

Tags: linux, scripting, scalability, ppp

I have a linux box with a bank of modems and need to create demand-dial (outbound) PPP connections to a very large set of remote machines.  Since I have far more remotes than local modems, I'd like to launch one or more instances of `pppd` in `demand` mode, but not allocate a particular modem until a connection is requested.  When the connection becomes idle, I'd like `pppd` to release the modem so it can be used for a connection to a different remote.

I've been through the `pppd man` pages and understand the concepts of the `call` and `connect` options, as well as the `options.DEVICE` files and the `/etc/ppp/peers` directory.  Lock files will tell me which modems are in use or available.  And I'm able to connect to multiple remote peers as long as I hard-code the modem assignments.  But I haven't found a way to assign them dynamically, say by calling a `get_available_modem` script when `pppd` needs to dial.  Google doesn't seem to know, either.

A work-around might be to detect the need to demand-dial with an external mechanism, and then launch `pppd` to service it, but it seems cleaner to leverage the facility within `pppd` itself.

Any pointers or ideas are appreciated.  Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: I haven't had to mess with demand-dialing with Linux and pppd since the 1990s...I can't remember how I used to do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I'm going with:

- Enumerate the modems as `/dev/modem0`, `/dev/modem1`, ...
- Start an instance of `pppd` in demand-dial mode for each peer, but instead of a "real" modem, attach it to `/dev/modem.`*peer*, which the "ppp-on-dialer" script soft-links to the first available modem dynamically.
- When the connection times out and the modem goes offline, soft link `/dev/modem.`*peer* to `/dev/null` so the modem can be re-used for a connection to a different peer.

Thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be directly driven by the Linux box, or could you use something like the old Lucent Portmaster boxen?

Comment: The linux box is custom hardware with a USB modem bank attached.  It's responsible for routing network traffic from a NOC to remote sites, either over the Internet or via PPP over dial-up.  We need to manufacture them, so and 3rd-party solution must be generic and inexpensive.  Thanks for your idea!